# When Iblis said: "My Lord! Grant me respite till the Day when they will be resurrected."

Tags: tafseer

When iblis refused to prostrate, how did iblis know about the day of resurrection, when he said: "My Lord! Grant me respite till the Day when they will be resurrected."?

I mean, did he know we were going to be sent on earth? Or was Adam in another jannah, since the Quran states no eye has seen paradise and it is not heard of.

Answer (score 2):

He would've known due to Allah (ﷻ) having revealed this information. At that point, it was common knowledge that humanity was going to be placed on earth because Allah (ﷻ) told the Angels this before Adam was even created.

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make upon the earth a successive authority." They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I know that which you do not know." - [Quran 2:30](https://quran.com/2/30)

And since Iblis was still among the Angels at this point, he would've heard that message as well.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for Iblis being among the angels? A satisfactory explanation would be helpful.

Comment: The same evidence that Ahl Al Sunnah has used for 1400 years i.e., Qur'an 17:61.

Comment: Verse 17:61 is no evidence for Iblis being an Angel and it can be refuted by 18:50 which makes clear that Iblis was in the same gathering with the angel but he actually is a Jinn. Among all scholars -AFAIK- only at-Tabari held this opinion that Iblis was angel at a certain time (For further information see for example [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/6485)). So Ahl-Sunnah have no consensus on this matter. The most important and missing here is why Iblis was among the angels? This point is hardly addressed in your answer. I think I've mentioned something in this context in one of my answers.

Comment: I said Iblis was *among* the Angels i.e., in their company, not that he was one. Please stop trying to find reasons to argue with me.

Comment: I'm trying to help you improve your answer and clarifying all possible misunderstandings and removing ambiguities. And consider having the beginning of (49:12) in mind.

Comment: If that is your intention then thank you. Though a simple "what do you mean" suffices too :)

Answer (score -1):

I will try to answer first part of your question.

My understanding is that we are told in Quran, in various verses, a fraction of the conversations between Allah and angels and iblis, during the creation of the first human(s). I mean, Quran tells some of the things -which are important for us to know-, but possibly not all the things that was said at that time (what angels know, what iblis knows etc.).

As you also quoted, iblis asks time from Allah in verse **15:36**, saying something along the lines of "*until the day they will be resurrected*". Based on the wording in this verse, at that time of speaking, iblis seems to know that humans will be resurrected (but the information about when the resurrection day will happen belongs only to Allah, verse **31:34**).

Just before the above mentioned verse where iblis asks for time, in verses **15:34** and **15:35**, Allah says to iblis, as I understand, "*this curse (iblis being expelled from where it was) will be upon you (iblis), until the day of judgment/recompense (day of resurrection)*". So, if you read 15:34-35, then read 15:36, it makes sense to think that iblis does know, at that time of speaking, that there will be a day of judgment for the humans, in which humans will be resurrected and judged based on their deeds.

Comment: "My understanding from Quran is that there is no definitive information about where Adam and his wife were put after creation, till eating from the forbidden tree." You should correct your understanding by re-reading the verses [2:35](https://legacy.quran.com/2/35), [7:19](https://legacy.quran.com/7/19) (and go further at least until 7:27) and 20:117 - 20:121 -which you are quoting- actually implies that they have been in Jannah! We may not -definitely- know where they have been right after their creation, but before eating from the tree they have surely been in Jannah.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thank you for pointing that. I still can't tell for sure, based on what I read from Quran, if the place Adam and his wife were put before being sent to Earth is the same place where people who earn Heaven will be put after the judgment day. It is possible that they are the same place, but it is also possible that Allah has created (or will create) multiple such places which have similar characteristics. Either way, I felt it would be better to remove that part of my answer.